# Computing Moving Average in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm working on learning Haskell, so I tried to implement a moving average function. Here is my code:

```
mAverage :: Int-> [Int] -> [Float]
mAverage x a = [fromIntegral k / fromIntegral x | k <- rawAverage]
    where
    rawAverage = mAverage' x a a

-- First list contains original values; second list contains moving average computations
mAverage' :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
mAverage' 1 a b = b
mAverage' x a b = mAverage' (x - 1) a' b'
    where
    a' = init a
    b' = zipWith (+) a' (tail b)
```

where the user calls mAverage with a length for each average and the list of values (e.g. `mAverage 4 [1,2..100]`).

However, when I run the code on the input `mAverage 4 [1,2..100000]`, I get that it takes 3.6 seconds in ghci (using `:set +s`) and uses a gigabyte of memory. This seems very inefficient to me, as the equivalent function takes a fraction of a second in Python. Is there some way that I could make my code more efficient?

Comment: Notice: `init a` is _O(length a)_, sort of expensive. It would be great to implement the sliding window so that moving it one item forth is constant time.

Comment: GHCi should not be used for anything performance related.  I suggest `ghc -O2` or `jhc`.

Comment: One way to do the sliding window is to pass in the first sum as a `Float`, pass in the original list (to be used to subtract from the current sum) and the original list with k entries dropped (to be used to add to the current sum). Then the next sum is the sum passed in minus the first element of the subtraction list plus the first element of the addition list.

Comment: Don't edit a question to change it so radically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a straightforward list-based solution which is idiomatic and fast enough, though requires more memory.

```
import Data.List (tails)

mavg :: Fractional b => Int -> [b] -> [b]
mavg k lst = take (length lst-k) $ map average $ tails lst
   where average = (/ fromIntegral k) . sum . take k
```

This solution allows to use any function instead of `average` in a moving window.

The following solution is less universal but it is constant in space and seems to be the fastest one.

```
import Data.List (scanl')

mavg :: Fractional b => Int -> [b] -> [b]
mavg k lst = map (/ fromIntegral k) $ scanl' (+) (sum h) $ zipWith (-) t lst
  where (h, t) = splitAt k lst
```

Finally, the solution which uses  a kind of Okasaki's persistent functional queue, to keep the moving window. It does make sense when dealing with streaming data, like conduits or pipes.

```
mavg k lst = map average $ scanl' enq ([], take k lst) $ drop k lst
  where 
    average (l,r) = (sum l + sum r) / fromIntegral k

    enq (l, []) x = enq ([], reverse l) x
    enq (l, (_:r)) x = (x:l, r)
```

And as it was mentioned in comments to the original post, do not use `ghci` for profiling. For example, you won't be able to see any benefits of `scanl'` in `ghci`.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to learn something new you can take a look at this nice solution for *Moving Average* problem. It is written by one of my students so I won't claim authorship. I really like it because it's very short. The only problem here is `average` function. Such functions are known to be bad. Instead you can use [*Beautiful folds by Gabriel Gonzalez*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6a5Ti0r8Q2s). And yes, this function takes ***O(k)*** time (where `k` is size of window) for calculating average of window (I find it better because you can face floating point errors if you try to add only new element to window and subtract last). Oh, it also uses `State` monad :)

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}

module MovingAverage where

import           Control.Monad       (forM)
import           Control.Monad.State (evalState, gets, modify)

moving :: Fractional a ⇒ Int → [a] → [a]
moving n _  | n <= 0 = error "non-positive argument"
moving n xs = evalState (forM xs $ \x → modify ((x:) . take (n-1)) >> gets average) []
  where
    average xs = sum xs / fromIntegral n
```

Comment: Why is the average function considered *bad* here? Divide by 0 edge case?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski That's one problem. Another problem is that this function traverses the list twice: first to find the sum and then to find `length` (finding `length` of a list in Haskell takes linear time). However, both the sum and the length can be computed in a single list traversal.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for you.

The idea is to scan *two* lists, one where the averaging window starts, and another where it ends. Getting a tail end of a list costs as much as scanning the part we're skipping, and we're not copying anything. (If the windows size was usually quite large, we could calculate the `remaining_data` along with counting the `sum initial_data`, in one go.)

We generate a list of partial sums as described in my comment, then divide them by the windows width to get averages.

While `slidingAverage` calculates averages for biased position (window width to the right), `centeredSlidingAverage` calculates centered averages, using half window width to the left and to the right.

```
import Data.List (splitAt, replicate)

slidingAverage :: Int -> [Int] -> [Double] -- window size, source list -> list of averages
slidingAverage w xs = map divide $ initial_sum : slidingSum initial_sum xs remaining_data
  where
    divide = (\n -> (fromIntegral n) / (fromIntegral w))  -- divides the sums by window size
    initial_sum = sum initial_data
    (initial_data, remaining_data) = splitAt w xs

centeredSlidingAverage :: Int -> [Int] -> [Double] -- window size, source list -> list of averages
centeredSlidingAverage w xs = slidingAverage w $ left_padding ++ xs ++ right_padding
  where
    left_padding = replicate half_width 0
    right_padding = replicate (w - half_width) 0
    half_width = (w `quot` 2)   -- quot is integer division

slidingSum :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -- window_sum before_window after_window -> list of sums
slidingSum _ _ [] = []
slidingSum window_sum before_window after_window = new_sum : slidingSum new_sum new_before new_after
  where
    value_to_go = head before_window
    new_before = tail before_window
    value_to_come = head after_window
    new_after = tail after_window
    new_sum = window_sum - value_to_go + value_to_come
```

When I try `length $ slidingAverage 10 [1..1000000]`, it takes less than a second on my MBP. [Due to the laziness](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/294658/11732), `centeredSlidingAverage` takes about the same time.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of doing it that also uses O(n) complexity

```
movingAverage :: (Fractional a) => Int -> [a] -> [a]
movingAverage n _ | n <= 0 = error "non-positive argument"
movingAverage n xs = fmap average $ groupBy n xs
  where average xs' = sum xs' / fromIntegral (length xs')

groupBy :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy _ [] = []
groupBy n xs = go [] xs
  where
    go _ []      = []
    go l (x:xs') = (x:t) : go (x:l) xs'
      where t = take (n-1) l
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use STUArray.

```
import           Data.Array.Unboxed
import           Data.Array.ST
import           Data.STRef
import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Monad.ST

movingAverage  :: [Double] -> IO [Double]
movingAverage vals = stToIO $ do
  let end = length vals - 1
  myArray <- newArray (1, end) 0 :: ST s (STArray s Int Double)
  forM_ [1 .. end] $ \i -> do
    let cval = vals !! i
    let lval = vals !! (i-1)
    writeArray myArray i ((cval + lval)/2)
  getElems myArray
```