# Decomposing type as seed in fold

Tags: haskell

I have the following problem:

I want to calculate the sum of the first `n` numbers and keep the count of each added number on every iteration. Therefore i defined a type:

```
data Avg = Avg { sum :: Int, count :: Int }
```

I need to use a seed of type `Avg` in a `foldl'` but i need it decomposed inside the aggregator function:

```
bang :: [Int] -> IO ()
bang ls@(x:xs) = printAvg $ foldl ' (\x y -> (x sum+y count+1) ) (Avg 0 0) ls

printAvg :: Avg -> IO ()
printAvg av = putStrLn . show (fromIntegral $ sum av / fromIntegral $ count av)
```

So my question is:

Given a type `data T = T { a :: Int, b :: Int }` and given a variable `myvar` of type `T`, how can I place it for pattern matching instead of its data constructor?

In my example the `foldl'` takes an `Avg` which is the `seed` and one element from the list.

I need `(\x y-> (x sum+y  count+1))`  instead of  `(\x y-> (Avg sum+y  count+1))`.

Comment: Try `(\ (Avg s c) y-> Avg (s+y) (c+1))`

Comment: Oh...i can pattern match on the left side of the lambda.That is precisely what i needed.

Comment: Side note: if your input is going to be at all large, it’d be good to make the fields of `Avg` strict (`sum :: !Int, count :: !Int`) or strictly match on them (`\ (Avg !s !c) -> …` with `BangPatterns`) to avoid a possible space leak—as it is, you’re not forcing the *contents* of the record until you do something with the result of the fold, so you’re accumulating a series of thunks, e.g., `Avg { sum = ((0 + 1) + 2) + 3, count = ((0 + 1) + 1) + 1 }`.

Comment: Oh but i thought that using `foldl'` would be enough to not have thunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few possible solutions:

```
(\ (Avg s c) y -> Avg (s + y) (c + 1))
-- equivalent to the longer
(\ x y -> case x of Avg s c -> Avg (s + y) (c + 1))

-- mentioning the fields name explicitly
(\ Avg{sum=s, count=c} y -> Avg (s + y) (c + 1))

-- using the RecordWildCards extension
(\ Avg{..} y -> Avg (sum + y) (count + 1))

-- using the two projections
(\ x y -> Avg (sum x + y) (count x + 1))
```

or even, adapting your code

```
bang::[Int]->IO()
bang ls@(x:xs) = printAvg $ foldl' foo (Avg 0 0) ls
   where
   foo (Avg s c) y = Avg (s + y) (c+ 1)
```

(using `let foo .. in ..` is also possible)

Answer (score 1):

Since `data Avg = Avg { sum :: Int, count :: Int }` is isomorphic to `(Int, Int)`, you could also fold with a tuple:

```
average :: Fractional r => [Int] -> r
average = uncurry (/) . foldr (\x (sum, count) -> (sum+x, count+1)) (0,0)

bang :: [Int] -> IO ()
bang = putStrLn . show . average
```

And if you want to keep the average running, you could use a `newtype` wrapper:

```
newtype Count = Count (Int, Int)

accumulate :: [Int] -> Count
accumulate = foldr accum (Count (0, 0))
  where
    accum :: Int -> Count -> Count
    accum x (Count (sum, count)) = Count (sum+x, count+1)

average :: Fractional r => Count -> r
average (Count (x, y)) = x / y

bang :: [Int] -> IO ()
bang = putStrLn . show . average . accumulate
```

You might risk overflows in both cases.

Consider finding a [moving average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41351442/computing-moving-average-in-haskell) (Haskell).